# (Beginner) Install on new Lenovo Tiny M80q, no OS, only wireless keyboard/mouse and USB-C monitor

Tags: system-installation, keyboard, mouse, lenovo, monitor

Thanks for any help you can offer me. I'm a new Linux user, this is my first ever AskUbuntu question, and it feels like a complex one, so thank you for your patience!

I've seen other questions which have some overlap, but because of the combination of factors here I wanted to ask a new question. Hope that's alright.

**Context**

I'm a professional voiceover artist taking the plunge and trying to switch from Windows to Linux for audio production.

I'm not a computing expert, but not a total beginner either.

I've done some research into Linux distros, learnt a little about the basic file system, made a bootable USB drive, used Virtualbox to explore a bit of the terminal on a virtual Linux machine. Fundamentally though I'm still a low-confidence Linux newbie.

**Overal Goal**

I'd like to install Linux (ideally Ubuntu Studio) on a brand new mini desktop PC, and connect it to a wireless keyboard, wireless mouse and USB-C monitor.

**Details**

The new PC is a Lenovo Thinkcentre M80q Tiny (11DNCTO1WW). Specs below:

**Processor**  -  10th Generation Intel® Core™ i3-10100T Processor (4 Cores / 8 Threads, 3.00 GHz, up to 3.80 GHz with Turbo Boost, 6 MB Cache) //
**Operating System**  -  Dos //
**Operating System Language**  -  No Operating System //
**Form Factor**  -  Tiny //
**Memory**  -  8 GB SO-DIMM DDR4 2666MHz //
**Video Adapter**  -  Integrated Graphics //
**Second Hard Drive**  -  256 GB M.2 2280 SSD //
**Optical Device**  -  Slim DVD Rambo 9.0mm //
**WiFi Wireless LAN Adapters**  -  Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201 (2x2 AX) vPro & Bluetooth® 5.1 //
**Default USB Port**  -  1 Front USB-C Port, 1 Front USB Port, 4 Rear USB Ports //
**USB-C Port**  -  USB-C Port //
**Rear Com Cable**  -  Serial Port Cable //
**Dust Shield**  -  Dust Shield for Tiny //
**Power Adapter**  -  135W adapter //
**Speakers**  -  Internal Speaker //
**VESA Mount**  -  VESA Mount //
**Tool-less for Open Chassis**  -  Tool-less for Open Chassis //
**Publications Pack**  -  Publication-English //
**Warranty**  -  3 Year On-site

The new PC has shipped with no native OS, and I'm hoping to run Ubuntu Studio on it.

In preparation, I downloaded UNetbootin on my current Windows laptop and did manage to create a bootable USB for Ubuntu Studio. I succesfully ran a few live-boot sessions from it on the Windows laptop, so I'm tentatively comfortable with that process.

However, unlike the laptop, this new PC has no monitor, keyboard or mouse.

I have a wireless keyboard, wireless mouse, and USB-C monitor, to create what I'm hoping will eventually be a fairly flexible set-up. The keyboard and mouse work happily with the current windows laptop, but the USB-C monitor is new and I haven't yet managed to try it out on the laptop, so could be trickier on the new PC too. It has a disk for the drivers. Full details of these accessories are at the end.

As these different bits of hardware all have their own drivers, this seems to throw up a whole series of questions regarding setting up the new PC, which I'm hoping you can help me with.

**Primary Questions**

**1.** Will I need to install a different distro other than Ubuntu Studio in order to just get the PC up and running - with monitor, mouse and keyboard?

**2.** Will I need a different, more plug-and-play Linux friendly keyboard / monitor / mouse combo first, before I can install any drivers for the wireless keyboard, mouse and USB-C monitor?**

**3.** Or can I manage this installation without any keyboard / mouse / monitor?

**Headless Installs?**

I've seen some information about 'headless installs' which seem to cover installation without monitor or keyboard etc.

My old windows laptop has an optical drive and can burn to disks, and the new PC has an optical drive too. So it seems I have the kit to be able to do this 'headless install' via disk.

However, a lot of the guidance I've seen on this seems to
a) focus on making a server rather than setting up a full desktop environment with a GUI...and
b) be quite complex for a Linux newbie - making install scripts etc. I'm very happy to invest the time and learn, but I just need to know where to start.

**Other Options?**

Other than a disk-based headless install, could you suggest other install options for my hardware setup and level of Linux experience?

These are the other resources I have to play with:

- Current Windows laptop, able to write to DVD / CD.
- Virtualbox on same laptop, with a test Lubuntu virtual machine set up.
- Serial Port, on both old laptop and new PC. (need serial port cable)
- Wifi connection.
- Ethernet Cable + ports on old laptop and new PC.
- USB with existing bootable Ubuntu Studio image.
- New, empty 16GB USB (Sandisk)

If you're reading this, thank you so much. I know this was a long question.

Other details on keyboard / mouse / monitor specs are below.

All answers gratefully appreciated. Thank again!

Ciaran

---

**Accessories Specs**

**Wireless Keyboard:** Advent Wireless Multimedia Keyboard (AKBMM15) // 2.4GHZ Wireless connection with USB nano receiver // OS Compatibility: Windows 10/8/7/Vista, Mac OSX // Frequency Band(s): 2403 - 2477 MHz // Max. radio frequency power transmitted: Keyboard: -19dBm, Dongle: -1dBm.

**Wireless Mouse:** Anker Wireless Vertical Mouse (TM137G) // 2.4GHZ Wireless connection with USB nano receiver // OS Compatibility: Linux, Windows 8/7/Vista/XP/2000, Mac OSX // Working Voltage: 3V // Working Current: 5mA.

**USB-C Monitor** AOC I1601FWUX Portable USB-C 16-inch LCD Monitor (156LM00007) // OS Compatibility: Windows 10/8/7, Mac IOS 10.12.1 or more // Driving System: TFT Color LCD // Optimal preset resolution: 1920x1080@60Hz // Plug & Play: VESA DDC2B/CI // Input Connector: USB Type-C (DP Alt mode) // Power Source: Notebook USB 5V // Power Consumption: 8 W, Standby <0.3 W.

Comment: Try not to overthink this. Connect the keyboard, mouse, and monitor to your Lenovo. Plug the bootable USB stick into an available port. If you plan in using an Ethernet connection, plug that in, too. Then start the machine. If things don’t work as expected, *that* is the time to ask questions. You already have all of the basics, so it’s just a matter of putting them together 

Comment: Wise words...Will try that for starters and post an update with what happens. Thanks!

Comment: Matigo, a follow-up question to your post: Will the bootable USB start up if there's no way of inputting keyboard commands? When I live-booted on a windows laptop I had to press Esc several times to enter the BIOS, then use keyboard keys to navigate and select the boot option. Will I have to use any keys to get the USB to boot properly? Thanks again!